# How to reference a file in Finder with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder

I have a really simple question, I've googled for a pretty long time but was unable to fix it:

```
            tell application "Finder"
                set videoFile to "Users:username:Desktop:No Backup:Music:video.mp4"
                delete file videoFile
            end tell
```

This results in the following error:

> Finder got an error: Can’t get file "Users:username:Desktop:No
> Backup:Music:video.mp4".

The same happens if I try "open file" or some other command instead of "delete".

However, the following does open the file correctly:

```
            tell application "QuickTime Player"
                set videoFile to "Users:username:Desktop:No Backup:Music:video.mp4"
                open videoFile
            end tell
```

This opens the video, so the file path must be correct.

I've also searched for a list of all the Applescript Finder commands but was unable to find anything that seemed like a proper documentation.

Edit: I also tried
I tried `delete (every item of folder folderPath whose name is "video.mp4")`, but this results in `Finder got an error: Can’t get folder "Users:username:Desktop:No Backup:Music".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HFS path must start **always** with a disk name (replace `Macintosh HD` with the real name)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set videoFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Desktop:No Backup:Music:video.mp4"
    delete file videoFile
end tell
```

However there is a convenient way to use relative paths regardless of the name of the startup disk and the user name

```
set desktopFolder to path to desktop as text -- returns "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Desktop:"
tell application "Finder"
    set videoFile to desktopFolder & "No Backup:Music:video.mp4"
    delete file videoFile
end tell
```

In case of the desktop folder of the current user there is a still shorter way because the desktop folder is the *root* folder of the Finder

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete file "video.mp4" of folder "No Backup:Music:"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add "Macintosh HD:" to the beginning of the file path – really confuses me that this behaves inconsistently between different apps

Comment: There is no inconsistency if you follow the rules. A POSIX path starts with a slash (which represents the startup disk) and an HFS path starts with a disk name.

Comment: Old-style Mac OS paths (the type AppleScript uses, for historical reasons) start with the volume name (see the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html)). I'm not sure why it worked without that with QuickTime Player, although note that you didn't pass it as a `file`, just as a string.

Comment: Filesystem operations are best handled using _System Events_ rather than _Finder_.  Among loads of other reasons, you can use the more familiar posix path format, i.e. `tell app "System Events" to delete file "~/Desktop/No Backup/Music/video.mp4"` (however, beware that System Events's **`delete`** removes the file from your system immediately rather than moving it to the trash).